# Real-time data streaming using Wikipedia's RecentChanges API

Tags: rest, apache-nifi, wikipedia-api

I'm lately trying to create a demo on real time streaming using NiFi -> Kafka -> Druid -> Superset. For the purposes of this demo I chose to use [Wikipedia's RecentChanges API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:RecentChanges) in order to get asynchronous data of the most recent changes. 
I use this [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges&rcprop=title%7Cids%7Csizes%7Cflags%7Cuser%7Cuserid%7Ctimestamp&format=json) in order to get a response of changes. I'm calling the API constanlty in order to not miss any changes. This way I get a lot of duplicates that I do not want.
 Is there anyway to parameterize this API to fix it for example getting all the changes from the previous second and doing that everysecond or something else to tackle this issue. I'm trying to make a configuration for this uing NiFi, if someone has to add something on that part then visit this discussion on [Cloudera](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Real-time-data-streaming-using-Wikipedia-API-NiFi-Duplicates/td-p/281102).

Comment: Why not use the [event stream](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Event_Platform/EventStreams)?

Comment: @Tgr I didn't know that an API like this existed, it is great thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brecentchanges Use rcstart and rcend to define your start and end times. You can use "now" for rcend.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response smartse. If I set rcend to now then what should be the definition of rcstart to lets say get the previous 5 seconds.

Comment: You'll have to fetch the current time and then minus 5 seconds. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Timestamp for accepted formats. Tgr's suggestion is probably more elegant however.

Comment: Yeah I think that approach it closer to what I need but I face some issues consuming that stream it can't be addressed in the same way as the API because it follows server-sent events protocol

Comment: @smartse +1 that's a good start. I proposed a solution in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553360/401025

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand smartse's answer and come up with a solution. You want to put your API request in certain time windows, by shifting the start and end parameters. Windowing might work like this:

- Initialize start, end timestamp parameters
- Put those parameters as attributes on the flow
- Downstream processors can call the API using those parameters
- After doing that, you have to set start = previous_end + 1 second and end = now

When you determine the new window for the next run, you need the parameters from the previous run. This is why you have to remember those values. You can achieve this using NiFi's distributed map cache.

I've assembled a flow for you:

[image]

Zoom into `Get next date range`:

[image]

The end parameter is always now, so you just have to store the start parameter. `FetchDistributedMapCache` will fetch that for you and put it into `stored.state` attribute:

[image]

`Set time range` processor will initialize the parameters:

[image]

Notice that end is always now and start is either an initial date (for the first run) or the last end parameter plus 1 second. At this point the flow is directed into the `Time range` output, where you can call your API downstream. Additionally you have to update the stored.value. This happens in the `ReplaceText` processor:

[image]

Finally you update the state:

[image]

The lifecycle of the parameters are bound to the cache identifier. When you change the identifier, you start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Upvote I'm definitely going to try your version, I really appreciate that you created a whole flow for me to understand. In order to solve my problem I went with Tgr's suggestion and I created a Kafka producer using python that reads an HTTP stream ([EventStream](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Event_Platform/EventStreams)) that respects the SSE protocol. I do all my transformations with python code and the whole process is real time I got great results in Superset. If someone needs more info on that I'm glad to help